# MFC PreCreateWindow to create a window that fill the screen except for the taskbar

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to create a window that fills the entire space of the desktop without including the Windows start menu, and without maximizing the window.

I think the code should be something like this :

```
BOOL CWnd::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    cs.cx = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN); 
    cs.cy = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); // minus start menu height please

    return CMDIFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

But how do I get the height of the start menu ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean Start menu or task bar? Do you also want to avoid docked appbars?

Comment: Taskbar yes. Yes for the appbars as well if possible.

Comment: Don't you need to modify the structure after calling the base class's implementation?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the taskbar and any appbars, you want to fill the work area. Use the `GetMonitorInfo` function and look at the `rcWork` member. (Note that each monitor has a different work area, so you need to know which monitor you care about.)